# Too many independent cubic polynomials in an ideal $I\subset \mathbb C[x,y,z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let us consider the ideal $I=(x^2-x,y,xz)\subset \mathbb C[x,y,z]$.

> I want to prove that $I$ contains (exactly) $5$ linearly independent
>   polynomials of degree $3$.

In three variables, we have $6$ linearly independent monomials: $x^2,y^2,z^2,xy,xz,yz$ of degree $2$. Since $y\in I$, when we multiply them by $y$ we land in $I$, i.e. we find $$yx^2,y^3,yz^2,xy^2,xyz,y^2z\in I.$$ It seems to me that these stay linearly independent in the subspace $I\cap \mathbb C[x,y,z]_3$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$, or some other ring?

Comment: @ZhenLin: Over $\mathbb C$, yes.

Comment: @user26857: I believe(d) that $I$ belongs to the Hilbert scheme of ideals with Hilbert function $T+2$ (this means that there are $k+2$ linearly independent polynomials of degree $k$ in $I$, for $k$ big enough). It seems I am wrong, though.

Comment: @user26857: What do you mean by the Hilbert series of $I$, a non-graded ideal? It seems to me that there are exactly $8$ monomials in $I \cap \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]_3$, as $x^3$ and $z^3$ are missing. Brenin: in general (for a graded ideal!), unless you have a regularity bound, it can be hard to tell exactly when the Hilbert polynomial agrees with the Hilbert function. Just because they disagree at $k = 3$ does not mean they will not agree for larger $k$

Comment: @zcn: Thanks. So, when $k$ is not "big enough", can the Hilbert function take both too high and too low values? For some reason I thought it could only take "too low" values.

Comment: @Brenin: Yes, the Hilbert function can take values higher than the Hilbert polynomial, e.g. taking direct sums with a finite length module will not change the Hilbert polynomial, but will increase the Hilbert function in low degrees.

Comment: @zcn: Thanks for your comment. Can you please help me computing the Hilbert function of $I$? I am still struggling with this problem.